# Using Find.Address in VBA to get a range

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I'm trying to find the location of a specific string in vba.

The following code gives me the error: Run-time error 91: Object Variable or with block variable not set.

```
With Range("A2:A62")
         Position = .Find("Unplanned").Address
    End With
```

So I tried setting the variable with the following code which gave me the error: compile error type mismatch

```
With Range("A2:A62")
        Dim Position As Range
        Set Position = .Find("Unplanned").Address
    End With
```

So then I randomly tried this which gave me compile error:object required

```
With Range("A2:A62")
        Set Position = .Find("Unplanned ").Address
    End With
```

Is there a certain type I should be using or way of writing this that would work better? - I'm very new and self taught with VBA.

Comment: `.Address` returns a string. Instead, dim the position variable as a range, and just use `Set Position = .Find("Unplanned")`

Comment: When I did this: `With Range("A2:A62")
        Dim Position As Range
        Set Position = .Find("Unplanned")
        MsgBox Position
   End With ` This leaves Position as equal to "Unplanned" @basodre

Comment: And it should use `msgbox position.address`

Comment: Also you may get that error if the value is not found.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a way to then split the address string out/use it to select the cell as well as a number of other cells in the row so that I can merge them together?

Comment: Just use `Cells(Position.Row,TheColumnNumberDesired)`

Comment: Chaining anything on the end of `Find()` is asking for runtime errors unless you're absolutely sure the `Find()` will succeed.  It's always safer to set a Range variable to the result of Find() and then test that for `Nothing` before proceeding.